# Custom emails during password confirmation while using composer require laravel/ui

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-blade, email-verification

Good afternoon. Please tell me,
how can you substitute your custom letters while using

composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

in Laravel 9.

Is it possible to make sure that the user receives a password reset letter and an email confirmation email not from Laravel templates, but from my blade files?

in standard blade files /auth/emails
there are no such emails, which could be edited

Answer (score 0):

these blade files are inside vendor directory

you can publish them to your `resources/views/notifications/` or `resources/views/emails/` and edit them by

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`